# Bash scripting - Complex MYSQL statements

Tags: mysql, bash

So I am trying to take this:

```
SELECT  'cran_juniper' AS `set`, c.*
FROM    cran_juniper c
WHERE   ROW(c.device_fqdn, c.device_ip, c.interface, c.admin_state, c.link_state, c.description) NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  device_fqdn, device_ip, interface, admin_state, link_state, description
        FROM    cran_juniper_baseline
        )
UNION ALL
SELECT  'cran_juniper_baseline' AS `set`, b.*
FROM    cran_juniper_baseline b
WHERE   ROW(b.device_fqdn, b.device_ip, b.interface, b.admin_state, b.link_state, b.description) NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  device_fqdn, device_ip, interface, admin_state, link_state, description
        FROM    cran_juniper
        )
into outfile 'today.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
;
```

And insert it into a bash script.   Considering there's a SLEW of special characters all over this query, I am having a hard time finding a way to go about this.  Any assist would be magical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1st solution using *here-doc* :

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 <<'EOF'
SELECT  'cran_juniper' AS `set`, c.*
FROM    cran_juniper c
...
;
EOF
```

#### 2nd solution using a separate file

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 < file.sql # you will put all of your query within this file
```

#### Check

```
man bash | less +/here-doc
```

Comment: That was the one, and a lot easier than I thought it'd be.  Thank you!